# PagedJS overwrites CSS

Tags: html, css, css-paged-media

I need to use [Paged.js](https://www.pagedjs.org/) in combination with a custom CSS for tables.

Paged.js constantly overwrites my style. I even added `!important` to all properties but Paged.js still overwrites them.

Can I prevent Pagedjs from doing that? I am working with a local copy of the JS so I am easily able to change it.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

I just have solved my issue.

The guy who wrote the app imported a `bootstrap.css` and a `bootstrap.min.css`. The `bootstrap.css` is v3.3.5 and the `bootstrap.min.css` is v3.3.6. Don't ask my why. This project is a mess anyway.

The issues was a tiny `@media print` style in the 3.3.6 bootstrap which leaded to reset all background styles. Because pagesjs loads the `@media print` right into the HTML and the issue only showed up as I activated pagejs I thought that this must be the source.

Solution: Always check other dependencies